# Jenkins groovy script issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, aws-cloudformation

I have groovy Jenkins pipeline script and it is calling some AWS CLI commands and trying to parse JSON output and pass to the next CLI command executing in the shell. I always get an issue with the second one. Not sure why.

First AWS CLI I run to get the JSON and parse for the EC2 instance name.
The second command I pass the instance name from above and I am trying to check the status of the instance but that always fails.

```
String logicalenv= 'qa'
try {
    String scriptOutput =  sh(
            script: 'aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --logical-resource-id someresource --stack-name somestack-' + logicalenv,
            returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
    echo "scriptOutput: ${scriptOutput}"
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(scriptOutput)
    String instanceId = object.StackResourceDetail.PhysicalResourceId
    echo "instance id : ${instanceId}"

    String scriptOutput2 =  sh(
            script: 'aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ' + instanceId,
            returnStdout: true
            ).trim()

    echo "scriptOutput2: ${scriptOutput2}"
}
catch (Exception e) {
    echo "Error running the script"
}
```

```
SCRIPT OUTPUT
[Pipeline] sh
+ aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --logical-resource-id someresource --stack-name somestack-qa
[Pipeline] echo
scriptOutput: {
    "StackResourceDetail": {
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:NNNNNN:stack/somestack-qa/xxxx-xxx-xxxx0", 
        "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
        "DriftInformation": {
            "StackResourceDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
        }, 
        "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::Instance", 
        "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-09-26T20:50:33.577Z", 
        "StackName": "somestack-qa", 
        "PhysicalResourceId": "i-123456789", 
        "Metadata": "{}", 
        "LogicalResourceId": "someresource"
    }
}
[Pipeline] echo
instance id : i-123456789
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] echo
Error running the script
```

```
Was expecting something like below for the second command
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-123456789",
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-xx",
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Status": "ok",
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Status": "passed",
                        "Name": "reachability"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
If I just run by hardcoding the values
sh 'aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --logical-resource-id someresource --stack-name somestack-QA'
sh 'aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids i-123456789'
They return the JSON fine.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It must be not serializeable exception, which you are catching. try printing the value of exception in catch block. If that is the case then just use JsonSlurperClassic instead of JsonSlurper.

Comment: Nothing looks run in your script. You may want to check that the IAM policy for Jenkins allows `ec2:DescribeInstances` action

Comment: Jenkins has power user policy. Also when i run the script just by hardcoding the variables it works fine. Couldn't print stack trace because some scripts are denied by admin error. Issue is with the second sh command. But can't figure out what is wrong.